# How to open an existing doc/x file and then write on it?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I want to open an existing MS Word document, then write a specific text on it.

The existing document has this content:

> *First car costs ... $.*

I would like to add a specific text right after the word *costs*.
The final text should be :

> *First car costs 15000 $.*

I want to do this using a simple c# application.
I'm having difficulties to find a way to add text at the desired position.

I used a NuGet package called DocX.
Here is my code:

```
using Novacode;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
string fileName = @"C:\Users\DAFPC\Documents\WordDoc1.docx";
var doc = DocX.Load(fileName);
doc.ReplaceText("...", "15000",false, RegexOptions.None,  null, null,  MatchFormattingOptions.SubsetMatch,  true,  false);
 doc.Save();
 Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
```

The code does not replace "..." with "15000". But if I try to replace the word "Car" with "15000" the code works.

Comment: You forget to add the code you wrote so everybody can help you starting from there

Comment: Internally, `*.docx` files are stored as a directory of different files in a `*.zip` archive. Copy it to `xxx.docx.zip` and use a tool like `7z` to have a look. In theory, your code could modify the `document.xml` file, but it is probably easier to start a `Word` application and use the methods of the `Word Application` object to modify the `*.docx` file. Takes a bit of reading and learning, though.

Comment: I did it now @DamianLattenero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check edit**

```
doc.ReplaceText(toReplace, replacement);
```

You should wrap it in a function like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = "test.docx";
    ReplaceInDocx(filename, "...", "15000");
}

static void ReplaceInDocx(string filename, string toReplace, string replacement)
{
    var doc = DocX.Load(filename);
    doc.ReplaceText(toReplace, replacement);
    doc.Save();
}
```

You might find [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra) useful.

**Edit:** Ok, I see what you mean. The problem is with the way MS Word works. When you enter "..." it automatically gets converted into "…" (ellipsis). What you should do, then, is to search for that instead. Or better, change the search parameter.

```
ReplaceInDocx(filename, "…", "car");
```